# Angular 2's 5 times DOM performance booster when working with Side by Side

Tags: angularjs, performance, angular

I have an Angular 1.5 app.I have decided to upgrade it to Angular 2.Due to some dependencies with the 3rd party libraries where I cannot migrate it to angular 2 completely. So that I have decided to work on side by side mode.The key reason to migrate angular 2 immediately where I would like to get 5 times performance booster on the DOM creation of Angular 2.B'cos my app is having lot of drop downs where having 1K+ data.I have implemented `Redis` cache with those drop downs.But still it's having some delays due to the poor performance of Angular 1.X DOM creation.

**Q :** Can I get that 5 times performance booster if I work with both versions side by side ?

Comment: Create a test case and do some benchmarks

Comment: Sounds like your issues are just as much UX design problem as much as having to render 1000 items that user can't manage. There are certainly more friendly UI tools like typeahead/autocomplete that don't require heavy rendering

Comment: @charlietfl He can mange it hence all dd's are searchable ones.

Comment: what he is saying it that rendering more than 1k data might not be necessary as it would probably even not fit the user's screen or it would pollute it. too much dom will perform poorly, regardless of angular. i believe that this is the point he is trying to make. you can event keep it in memoery, but not rendered.

Comment: @WalterMacambira Yes,he is right.But my question was,can we get angular 2's performance improvements when we use both versions side by side ?